# Organization of c++ header files

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files, forward-declaration

Suppose I have a header file header1.h with typedefs A, B and C. B uses A and C uses B so the order of the typedefs is forced. Now I decide that typedef B really should be in its own header file (header2.h). But I cannot include header2 from header1 (because then typedef B would be before C), neither can I include header1 from header2. I tried to forward declare the types, but I think this only works when pointing to them. Otherwise the compiler still gives an 'incomplete type' error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only thing you can do here is move every typedef in its own header, then you can include them in arbitrary order. Like this:

`a.h`

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

typedef int A;

#endif // A_H
```

`b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

typedef A* B;

#endif // B_H
```

`c.h`

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "b.h"

typedef B& C

#endif // C_H
```